# Parsing with C++

Tags: c++, parsing

What's the easiest way to parse a file with

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [8, 9, 10, 11], ...]
```

into a vector of QRectF (a struct with four floats)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you looked at boost's spirit library? I think it's an amazing library and if I recall correctly they have examples in the tutorial very similar to what you want.

EDIT: This puts you at about the right place: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/warming_up.html

EDIT:
Sigh...I haven't looked at c++ in over a year (and I haven't looked at spirit in over 4 years) so this took about an hour to put together. Here's the working example:

```
# include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
using boost::spirit::qi::int_;
using boost::spirit::qi::char_;
using boost::spirit::qi::lit;
using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
using boost::spirit::ascii::space_type;
using boost::spirit::qi::rule;
using boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse;

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

struct holder {
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
    int n4;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(::holder, (int,n1) (int,n2) (int, n3) (int, n4))

int main() {
    string s = "[[1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1]]";
    vector<holder> v;

    // I admit it, I was wrong. It's 3 lines of parsing.
    rule<string::iterator, holder(), space_type> holder_p = 
        lit("[") >> int_ >> ',' >> int_ >> ',' >> int_ >> ',' >> int_ >> ']';
    rule<string::iterator, vector<holder>(), space_type > holder_list_p = 
        char('[') >> (holder_p % ',') >> ']';
    bool r = phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), holder_list_p, space, v);

    if (r) {
        for (vector<holder>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
            cout << "n1: " << it->n1 << ", n2: " << it->n2 << 
                    ", n3: " << it->n3 << ", n4: " << it->n4 << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, it looks great.  I'll try to modify one of the examples.  Thanks.

Comment: Update:  Spirit is kind of a nightmare for something so simple.

Comment: that is really amazing.  This should be one of the examples!

Answer (score 4):

IMO, Spirit is probably a bit of overkill for the job at hand. The format is simple enough that you can handle it pretty easily with the standard library. The real question is whether you need to check that the data is in the right format (verify the presence of all the brackets and comma) or if you just want to read the numbers. If you need to verify the format, you could do something like this:

```
// warning: untested code.
bool verify(char a, char b) { 
    return a == b;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, QRectF &r) { 
     char bracket, comma;
     float num[4];
     bool good = true;

     is >> bracket;
     good &= verify(bracket, '[');
     for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
         is >> num[i] >> comma;
         good &= verify(comma, ',');
     }
     is >> num[3];
     is >> bracket >> comma;
     good &= verify(bracket, ']');
     good &= verify(comma, ',');

     if (!good)
         is.setf(std::ios::failbit);
     else 
         for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
             r.value[i] = num[i];
     return is;
}
```

If you don't care about verifying the format, you can do pretty much the same, but get rid of all the `verify` stuff, as well as setting the stream state.

Alternatively, you can create a locale that treats everything except numbers as whitespace, so reading the data becomes trivial:

```
// warning: untested code:
struct digits_only: std::ctype<char> {
    digits_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        std::fill(&rc['0'], &rc['9'], std::ctype_base::digit);
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, QRectF &r) { 
    return is >> r.value[0] >> r.value[1] >> r.value[2] >> r.value[3];
}

int main() { 
    std::vector<QRectF> rects;
    std::ifstream infile("myfile.txt");
    infile.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new digits_only());

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<QRectF>(infile),
              std::istream_iterator<QRectF>(),
              std::back_inserter(rects));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, spirit is potentially overkill because of the dependencies. Your code could be better commented, though ;)

Comment: I hate it when people make claims like this. Spirit would do the job in like 1 line of very easy to read (and dare I say maintain) code. I like to say that there isn't bugs in code you don't have to write. Look how long that code is you wrote...why would you punish yourself like that?!

Comment: @Kevin: First of all, it's a bit more than one line. Second, for those who aren't accustomed to it, Spirit is almost completely unreadable. Third, in the first example above, about half the code is dedicated to something Spirit *won't do* anyway. Fourth, when/if you use a debugger, Spirit can be next to impossible to deal with at all. Fifth, while this particular parser probably won't cause a problem, doing anything large or complex with Spirit can lead to extremely long compile times. Sixth, while shorter code has benefits, it's hardly the sole measure of quality.

Comment: @kevin: The bottom line is that your hatred has little effect on reality, and the reality is that for a lot of people, Spirit is (and will remain) much more novel and impressive than truly useful.

Comment: @Kevin has a great point here.  Why reinvent the wheel when there is a really great third-party solution?  I think the "warning: untested code" comment in the sample code is quite illustrative in this case.

Comment: @Jerry: c++ is unreadable for those who aren't accustomed to it (food for thought!). Your tone suggests to me that spirit will always be overkill (to you) regardless the task.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, but there are lots of people who know C++ but not Spirit. I've found that Spirit is kind of caught between a rock and a hard place. When the grammar is sufficiently complex to justify a parser generator, Spirit's compile times are *usually* quite unreasonable.

Comment: @smithco: if all, or even most, of the other replies included tested code, you might have a point. If the code being untested indicates a problem, then kevin failing to include any code at all must indicate at least twice as much of a problem with Spirit! :-)

Comment: +1. I like Boost.Spirit but it's not for everyone - it's good to present alternatives. I also didn't know you could do that with locales, that can be useful to know.

Comment: @Jerry: I provided a link to documentation that gives several working examples. I try to avoid doing other people's work for them; since I have my own day job to worry about!

Comment: @kevin: I think it's safe to say we all have other responsibilities. With Spirit, however, links tend to be more problematic than in many other cases. I haven't looked at the ones you linked, but a *lot* of Spirit examples are actually for Spirit 1, and don't quite work with the current incarnation of Spirit.

Comment: Update: I ended up changing the input format to four numbers per line, no commas, no brackets, and an end-of-input sentinel, because it makes the parsing much easier.

@Kevin:  Please please show me how to do it in one line or even 30!  I was at around 50 lines when I gave up.  This is just out of curiosity as I know you are quite busy and I now have a workaround, but I am curious about Spirit.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and straightforward approach is to let the old `scanf` to deal with the formatted input:

```
QRectF rectf;
// deal with opening square bracket here.
int r = fscanf (file, "[%f, %f, %f, %f]", 
                &rectf.a, &rectf.b,
                &rectf.c, &rectf.d);
if (r == 4)
    // pasring succeeded.
// consume whitespaces and a comma/closing square-bracket here.
```

A complete C program that could read and parse an input file into `QRectF` objects is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct 
{
  float a;
  float b;
  float c;
  float d;
} QRectF;

static void skip_whitespaces (FILE*);

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{ 
  FILE* file = NULL; 

  if (argc <= 1)
    {
      printf ("please specify file name.\n");
      return 1;
    }

  file = fopen (argv[1], "r");

  if (!file)
    {
      printf ("failed to open file.\n");
      return 1;
    }
  if (fgetc (file) != '[')
    {
      printf ("expected [ not found.\n");
      fclose (file);
      return 0;
    }

  while (!feof (file))
    {
      QRectF rectf;
      int r, c;

      skip_whitespaces (file);
      r = fscanf (file, "[%f, %f, %f, %f]", 
                  &rectf.a, &rectf.b, &rectf.c, &rectf.d);
      if (r != 4)
        {
          printf ("invalid data format.\n");
          break;
        }
      else
        printf ("%f, %f, %f, %f\n", rectf.a, rectf.b, rectf.c, rectf.d);

      skip_whitespaces (file);  
      c = fgetc (file);
      if (c == ']')
        break;
      else if (c != ',')
        {
          printf ("expected , not found.\n");
          break;
        }
    }

  fclose (file);
  return 0;
}

static void 
skip_whitespaces (FILE* file)
{
  while (!feof (file))
    {
      int c = fgetc (file);
      if (!isspace (c))
        {
          ungetc (c, file);
          break;
        }
    }
}
```